# Increase Magic Mouse Scaling Over Max

Tags: macos, mouse

On a normal USB mouse you can change the mouse scaling in the terminal:

> `defaults write -g com.apple.mouse.scaling X`

Where `X` is your scale; in System Preferences the max scale is 3.0. When using this trick on a USB mouse, there is a very noticeable difference: the cursor moves further when you move the mouse. However this trick is not working on Apple Magic Mouse 1 or 2.

How can I achieve scaling over 3.0 using the Magic Mouse? Bonus points for anyone who can do it without third-party apps and can do it while disabling mouse acceleration.

Comment: First did you restart after you set it?  Second, this may be a Bluetooth limitation because using my Logitech BT mouse, I can't get over 3 either

Comment: I have not restarted my mac, but I have a program open that I cannot afford to close at the moment. I used a Logitech mouse as well, but a restart was not required everytime I changed the scale. What you do is you go to your name in the top right, and click "Login Window". Then log in, and it should work. But so far, every Bluetooth and USB mouse I've used has worked as expected.

Comment: It's not required every time, but it does need it sometimes.  To rule it out for the MM, you'll need to restart.   Also, remember that the MM is identified in NVRAM as is the keyboard because you can use it in the boot manager.  There may be a limitation because of this.

Comment: Makes sense. I'll try that. Did logging back in solve your issue?

Comment: Restart did not solve the issue.

Comment: Out of curiosity I started digging around BT and NVRAM.  It seems some BT mice work fine but mine (MX Master 3S) doesn't.  Interestingly, it doesn't see it as a mouse (`system_profiler SPBluetoothDataType`).  It's "blank" under services whereas the MM specifically says "Apple Wireless Mouse."  If I plug in a USB mouse, it gets identified as a proper mouse.  This may be the issue - or at least related to it.

Comment: I've given up on aa non-third-party solution, have you found one? At this point though, I'll take any solution